# Is there a way to exclude some files from submitting to the iOS app store

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on an app that i would like to submit to the store and i have some files that is part of the project that i don't want to be part of the archive.

For example some viewcontroller files that i made but are not going to use for this version of the app or some data files that i am reading into the database that not needed in the release.

Do i have to delete everything before creating the archive or i can some how choose for them not to be included.  Also some of the viewcontrollers on the storyboard are extras would i have to delete them also?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the environment you are using for development. E.g. I'm using SharpDevelop and XCode. Others are e.g. from Adobe or Borland (haha, joke, I don't know how the company is currently called).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am using Xcode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only files that are part of the target you're archiving will be included in the archive and submitted to the App Store. You can add or remove files from a target by selecting it and editing the checkbox in the file inspector panel on the right:

[image]

To see all the files that are included in your target, select your project in the file browser on the left. Then select your target and the **Build Phases** tab.

Under **Copy Bundle Resourses** you'll see all the resource files that will be added to your app's bundle (and the archive).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!  To exclude .m files then i would uncheck the target membership in the inspector and for other files like images and data files i would delete them from the the link binary with libraries and if i want to put them back i would just include them again.

Comment: Yes, but from **Copy Bundle Resources**, not **Link Binary With Libraries**. That's something else. You can just check or uncheck the checkbox in the panel on the right side or add/remove them from the Bundle Phases lists. It's just two different ways for the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can selectively exclude files from your Xcode project:

In your project settings, select your target. In your target, select Build Phases pane. From there, you can exclude compilation sources and bundle sources via the "Compile Sources" and "Copy Bundle Resources" lists.